# error in using toInt() function in android developement(Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I am getting error when i use toInt() function in android(**Kotlin**)

```
val num1=findViewById<EditText>(R.id.num1).text.toString()
val num2=findViewById<EditText>(R.id.num2).text.toString()
```

when i add toInt()

```
 val num1=findViewById<EditText>(R.id.num1).text.toString().toInt()
 val num2=findViewById<EditText>(R.id.num2).text.toString().toInt()
```

i am getting error when i run my app on my phone.
I am a newbie in android developement so i decided to make a simple app which calculate two numbers but when i try to use **toInt()** my app not run on my phone

**Note**:when i remove toInt() my app smoothly run on my phone.
[enter image description here][1]

screen shoot of error i am getting
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sl3cn.jpg

Comment: you should post what the actual error is you are getting

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sl3cn.jpg

Comment: That is not an image of the actual error thats juts the dialog that shows when you get one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possibly crashing while attempting to cast empty field values as numbers?

Try using [`toIntOrNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-int-or-null.html#tointornull) and let me know what happens.

Comment: yes it works but it gives null even i input integer

Comment: Excellent @AnkitPandey. For your next problem, if the fields are empty when these lines execute then num1 and num2 have had null assigned as their values.

Consider splitting your logic to first create a reference to your UI:
val field1 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.num1)

Then later inspect their contents when you wish:
val num1 = field1.text.toString().toIntOrNull()

Comment: Thank you so much sir  it is working now